# Is there a term for this style of ethnic European folk song?

Tags: folk, style, european

The style features verses that are slow, sometimes speeding up, but ending with a rallentando and often a fermata, then going into a chorus that begins slowly (sometimes *very* slowly) with a gradual accelerando that builds in volume and tempo to a frenetic pace. Then rinse and repeat.

Example: [Дорогой длинною](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsl9TIUFUSA)

Example: [Смуглянка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7OyiA1l8A)

This is distinct from [this kind of dance song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SPXDAX4Ci8) (a *hora*?), which starts quiet and slow but then builds throughout to a feverish pace and volume over the course of the entire piece.

Comment: This type of accelerando (or 'stringendo') is typical of Gypsy music.